# How can I overwrite file web.config with web.other.config?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a msbuild script with custom logic to deploy my service to the qa server automatically. I have to overwrite the default config with a dedicated one, but when I use `<Copy SourceFiles="web.other.config" DestinationFiles="web.config" />` it does nothing.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Looks like it should work ok. Is it definitely in a target that is getting executed. Is the path right? do you need to put the full path? or the relative path from wherever the msbuild script is being executed from?

Comment: I put full path, and yes, it definitely executes because I have a Message just before and after it.

Comment: Are you outputting the copied files in the message after? If yes, does it print the web.config?
    <Output TaskParameter="CopiedFiles" ItemName="SuccessfullyCopiedFiles"/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats exactly what I do in my build scripts and it looks fine.  Are you sure you not getting any file permission issues. when overwriting the file?

try deleting the destination file first if it already exists.

```
<Delete Files="web.config" ContinueOnError="false"></Delete>
<Copy SourceFiles="web.other.config" DestinationFiles="web.config"></copy>
```

Comment: Silly user error: I had <Copy SourceFiles="web.other.config" DestinationFiles="web.other.config"></copy>